# I can't predict server error?

Tags: error-handling

While running my application in server, an error is thrown:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 46900 bytes)
```

If anyone overcame my problem in experience, please help me.

Comment: Don't try to do so much in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is 134 megabytes a reasonable amount of memory for your application to be using?  If so, see if there is an option on the server to raise the maximum-memory-used limit.  If not, figure out why your application is using so much RAM.  Perhaps it has a memory leak?

Comment: We are using single php file with more than 8000 line. Whether this is the problem for running my application.